# what does <> mean in Python

Tags: python

What is the meaning of <> in Python?

I have tried searching for it on Google but I cannot seem to get inside the search term...

I have not seen this in any other language also otherwise I would have tried to find it.

Comment: For the record, Pascal (and therefore Delphi) and propably some other of Wirth's languages use it in the same way as Python.

Comment: BASIC is another language that uses this operator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`<>` is an alternate spelling of `!=`, the inequality test operator. IIRC, it has been removed in Python3.

```
>>> "foo" <> "bar"
True
>>> "foo" <> "foo"
False
```

Comment: I have never encountered <> in a python program, only !=.  Learn something new everyday.

Comment: @seggy - learn something new that should be forgotten as soon as possible :)   Unless, of course, you have to maintain OLD python code.

Comment: @KevinDTimm, Absolutely.  But I thought it was some sort of strange doc string syntax I'd never seen in a python program before. :)

Answer (score 3):

It is an obsolete inequality operator. See the Python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons).

> != can also be written <>, but this is
>   an obsolete usage kept for backwards
>   compatibility only. New code should
>   always use !=.

Answer (score 1):

`<>` means `not equal to`. `<>` and `!=` have the same meanings.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin):

> The forms <> and != are equivalent;
>   for consistency with C, != is
>   preferred; where != is mentioned below
>   <> is also accepted. The <> spelling
>   is considered obsolescent.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as != ("not equal")

Answer (score 0):

the <> operator is the same as != which means not equal to

```
if thing1 <> thing2:
   code here
```